# How to create object of this class?

Tags: java, android, class, object

I have following class with a constructor :

```
public class TestAdapter {

    protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

    private final Context mContext;
    private  SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private  DatabaseHandler mDbHelper;

//  private static SQLiteDatabase mDb2;
//  private static DatabaseHandler mDbHelper2;


    public TestAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
    }
```

In this very class I have a  `setFlag()` method which I need to call from following method -

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // tv.setText(result);
            Log.e("result", result);
            if (Integer.parseInt(result) == 1) {
                flagValue = 1;
                Log.e("my","flag value set");
                //TestAdapter t =new TestAdapter();
                //setFlag()



            }
```

the commented part is where I need to call that method but I don't know how to create object of the "TestAdapter" class. If I make setFlag() static in that class, then other instances being used in that method will not work because they are not static. F1  F1  F1

EDIT: I am given to understand that context exist for an activity but this class in which I need to create the object is not an activity..its just a java class which has methods to sync local database with server database.

Comment: What is the exact problem/error at the line where you are trying to create the object? You need to pass the `context` object as the constructor is parameterized.

Comment: can u please make the problem clear.
and where is the onPostExecute Method present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First declare in your Activity first declare on top `Context context = null;`

Then in onCreate `context = this;`.

Now you can use your method like:

`TestAdapter t = new TestAdapter(context); t.setFlag();`

Answer (score 1):

Simple Buddy,

In your `AsyncTask` Class's **Constructor** you have a **Context of Calling Activity**.

Like, `mContext`..

Now pass this context to your **TestAdapter's Constructor**.

Like,

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // tv.setText(result);
        Log.e("result", result);
        if (Integer.parseInt(result) == 1) {
            flagValue = 1;
            Log.e("my","flag value set");
            TestAdapter t =new TestAdapter(mContext);
            t.setFlag()
        }
```

Comment: If you don't have a `Context` of Calling Activity in `AsyncTask`. Then just use Name of Calling Activity as Context like, `<TempActivity>.this`

Answer (score 0):

Make **`TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(YourCurrentActivityName.this)`** in **`onCreate()`** Method.
Then call **`adapter.setFlag();`** method in **`onPostExecute()`** or where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
TestAdapter object = new TestAdapter(CurrentActivty.this);
```

In this way you can create object of `TestAdapter` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this way

```
TestAdapter t =new TestAdapter(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to help you if you said what error your IDE or LogCat gives you. 
Instantiate with Context, as required by your constructor.

```
            TestAdapter t =new TestAdapter(ctx);
            t.setFlag()
```

with ctx being your Context.